# Change color of a drawable from code (xamarin.android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been given some code to extend, for an android application.

The main activity has a FrameLayout which exhibits a Button. The button's background is a drawable (XML).

**==> resources/layout/Layout.axml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#999999">
    .../...
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_button"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/btn" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

The button uses a drawable to make it look round with a border.

**==> resources/drawable/btn.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#20000000"/>
      <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
      <size android:width="60dp" android:height="50dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
      <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
      <size android:width="60dp" android:height="50dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

At one point in the app's lifetime, the button's border (stroke above) should change color. How can I change the color of the stroke above ?
Using the usual `FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.the_button)` does not help.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION** - Thx to G.hakim

```
Button _theButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.the_button);
GradientDrawable _stroke = (GradientDrawable)_theButton.Background.Current;
_stroke.SetStroke(2, Color.Red);
```

Comment: You can try like `this var bgShape = (GradientDrawable)holder.BtnAttend.Background.Current;
                bgShape.SetColor(Color.ParseColor("#29AE53"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
var button= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.the_button);
var gradientDrawable = button.Background.Current as GradientDrawable;
gradientDrawable.SetColor(your_color);
```